# Class Design Problems (managing memory allocation & deallocation)

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list

1) So i have made a somewhat modified form of linked list that has indexed based addressing and other delete functions. I am just gonna copy the header file i made...

```
 template<class T>
    class LinkedList
    {
        public:
          LinkedList();
         ~LinkedList();
          int del_node();  // deletes the Node and element
          int remove_node();  // deletes the Node only
          int get_length();   
          int search_node(T*); // matches the pointer to see if its the same element
          void add(T*);
          void clear_list(); // calls deletes on all nodes and all elements
          bool is_blank(); 
          T& get_at(int);      // operates like a vector get_at
private:
      struct Node
      {
        T* element;  // pointer passed to add(T*) is stored here.
        Node* next;
     }
```

Now see how i am adding an object in a linked list. I need to pass in an object pointer which i am passing in the form of

`new Object()`

This is particularly useful when i am adding Vertices of a graph. I just input the data and other fields from the user and call

```
LinkedList graph
graph.add(new Vertex(arguments));
```

Now there comes a situation when i have to copy some elements from the `LinkedList` `A` to `B` for temporary storage. Now i want to be able to remove elements from `B` after any kind of operation. But if i use `delete` it destroys the internal Node and deletes the object pointed by the pointer `element` i passed to it. So i created an additional function `remove` that only deletes the Node but not the object pointed by the `element`.

So i wanted to ask if its okay to do this or is there a design fault in my list and i should not be doing this? I am thinking of this from a library point of view for example if i would go about providing this class in a library. Is this suitable or will this confuse people? Any advice would be appreciated.

> Please, I don't need any suggestions to use a replacement
>   function/class/library like vector. I am studying Data Structures and i have
>   to design any sort of data structure myself.

Comment: A suggestion you should adhere to is to not name your functions/variables/classes with c++ keywords, like `delete`.

Comment: oh yea actually i named it del xDD lemme correct it

Comment: Following on from Story Teller's comment - your header file would not even compile due to use of language keywords as function names.   Posting code like that tells other people you have just thrown the header together without much thought, and haven't even tried implementing the behaviour you describe.   You need to try a little harder than that.

Comment: @Peter - you want me to post my implementation?

Comment: Some selected parts, yeah.   And a `main()` function, along with any description of behaviours that aren't what you expect/hope for.

Comment: Did i talk about my program not compiling or unexpected behaviours? lol dude i just asked if my design is right. Do you really need a proof that i wrote this code inorder to give your answer on the design of this snippet? If you can't answer this don't come here.

Comment: In my opinion yes, there is a design fault. The container should own and manage the objects. The possibility to delete nodes but not the managed object makes things quite tricky. How do you enforce proper transfer of ownership once you remove a node? It can be done, but I wouldn't do it unless you have a specific need for it.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon - That's the part im doubting on... I am relying on the programmer to not use `remove_node` unless the object is already is stored in another linked list or somewhere else. If the object ain't stored anywhere and i call `remove_node` on the first list it will cause a memory leak

Comment: @wandering-warrior, you can only rely on the client programmer to try and achieve their goal. They will use & abuse any interface you give them. So you need to make sure it's easy to do the right thing, and difficult to do the wrong thing. Giving them really powerful API that can mess up the internals of your class, and expecting them to be cautious, will not work.

Comment: @wandering-warrior -- I want a linked list of `int`.  I give your linked list class an int, and it knows what to do to create the node and store what I give it.  I don't want to give a pointer to an int, just an int.  The client should not have to get into the weeds of nodes, pointers, etc.  That is *your* linked list's responsibility, not the client using the linked list.  Thus your design is highly flawed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Yes actually i had thought about it and provided an overloaded method that is `add(T element)` for primitives. I didn't need it in this project though so i haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: @wandering-warrior - *I didn't need it in this project though so i haven't implemented it yet* -- That's the flaw.  Your implementation should work regardless of the type sent to it. There should be no need to implement more functions for primitive types.  If for some reason, I actually do want to store pointers, I will give you an `int *` as the `T` argument to the template, not your list having to do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Sorry didn't understand. If you don't want me to implement a different function for `T` and `T*` how can you expect to pass both `int` and `int *` ?

Comment: @wandering-warrior -- Please see how `std::list` works.  If I want a linked list of `T`, it should work with `T`.  The `T` should be able to be anything, as long as it fits basic requirements (i.e copyable, assignable, etc,).  Pointers fall into these categories.

Comment: I finally got what you are saying thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more idiomatic fashion is to have `Node::~Node` always call `delete element;`, but add a `T* Node::release();`. This is what [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does for instance.

The implementation is straight forward:

```
T* Node::release()
{
  T* tmp = element;
  element = nullptr;
  return tmp;
}
```

That way the `Node` d'tor is still correct, but you can "save" the data from deletion.

This is also the first step in addressing what I sense is a flaw in your implementation. You implement all functionality in `LinkedList`, even that which is relevant to the behavior of the internal class `Node`. Don't do that. Give `Node` a role and an interface related to that role. Than have `LinkedList` work by using that interface.

Comment: Hmm ok i understand what you are talking about. But suppose the situation when i have a `LinkedList A`  already created. Now i used the `get_at()` operator to return some specific elements and store them in `LinkedList B`. Do note that `get_at()` returns original object so both Lists have the same object. So if i call delete on element won't List A get disturbed as too?

Comment: @wandering-warrior, than you are using the wrong language, you don't want to `T& get(int idx)` an element. You want to `T* remove(int idx)` it.

Comment: Right. This means that i shouldn't store 1 object in 2 different lists? i.e if i want to store an object of List A in List B i should reallocate memory and copy the data for storing in list B? Am i right?

Comment: @wandering-warrior, yes. If you have any sort of `T*` deletion, your class must have sole ownership of the pointed to object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Ownership should be explicit when designing your class.
For that, you can use explicit method names and return `std::unique_ptr` when you are transfering ownership. With explicit method names you should be able to remove your comments.

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
   public:
      LinkedList(const LinkedList&);
      LinkedList(LinkedList&&);
      LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&);
      LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList&&);
      void free_element(int);  // deletes the Node and element
      std::unique_ptr<T> extract_element(int);  // deletes the Node only
      int get_length() const;
      void add_element(std::unique_ptr<T>);
      void absorb_element(T*);
      void free_all_elements(); // calls deletes on all nodes and all elements
};
```